# Have Intermediate CMake Files Appear in the IDE

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, cmake

I am developing a system of build scripts for CMake and have an issue with wanting to have intermediate CMakeLists.txt files appear in the IDE for easier search and edit.

I have a main CMake file that includes a directory that includes several subdirectories for libraries.

```
CMakeLists.txt
--- SubProjects:
-------CMakeLists.txt
-------ProjectAFolder:
----------CMakeLists.txt
-------ProjectBFolder:
----------CMakeLists.txt
-------ProjectCFolder:
----------CMakeLists.txt
```

In the SubProjects folder, the CMakeLists.txt is very simple and just includes the subproject folders one after the other:

```
SET(SUBDIRECTORIES  ProjectAFolder
                    ProjectBFolder
                    ProjectCFolder )

foreach (subdirectory ${SUBDIRECTORIES})
    add_subdirectory(${subdirectory})
endforeach ()
```

However, when I generate this in XCode or Visual Studio, the IDE does not include the intermediate CMakeLists.txt file anywhere because it does not belong to any individual library or executable target. What is the best way to include this somewhere so it appears in an IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you want the file to show up, since it doesn't belong to any target. You can simply add it to any existing target (just as you do with source files) or you can create a new custom target.

```
add_library(AnyExistingTarget <other source files> SubProjects/CMakeLists.txt)
```

Or create a custom target:

```
add_custom_target(MyIntermediateCMakeFiles SubProjects/CMakeLists.txt)
```

For Visual Studio, you could also use the built-in support for cmake. It will display the source tree in the IDE without any extra work.